# WSS 3.0 installation on x64

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net, wss-3.0

*I'm getting the following error:*

Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error(s):
This product requires ASP.NET v2.0 to be set to 'Allow' in the list of Internet Information Services (IIS) Web Server Extensions. If it is not available in the list, re-install ASP.NEt v2.0

The steps I've taken after a new install of Windows Server 2003:

- Installed SQl Server 2005
- Installed .Net Framework 2.0 x64
- Installed .Net Framework 3.0 x64
- Verified that ASP.NET v2.0.50727 (32-bit) is set to Allowed in the IIS Web Service Extensions
- Attempted to install WSS 3.0, failing with the above error

I've tried running the following command to ensure that .Net 2.0 is being used

```
c:\windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Now I'm stuck, can anyone help?

P.S. I've also noticed that I have no ASP.NET tab when I view the properties for the default web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. IIS is required to run in 64bit mode only. It was running in 32/64bit mixed mode. Credit goes to [this blog post](http://jtoee.com/2008/05/installing-wss-30-on-2003-server-r2-64-bit/).

Run the following command in the command prompt to disable mixed-mode:

```
cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 0
```

And then re-install .net 2.0 like so:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

And verify that ASP.NET v2.0.50727 is set to Allowed in the IIS Web Service Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the 64 bit SQL 2005?  SQL 2005 installs .NET 2.0 if it's not already there.  I'm wondering if maybe you have a problem with 32 bit and 64 bit both being on the server if you installed the 32 bit SQL 2005.